# Null error while dynamically creating AWS Lambda from java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create lambda function from another lamda function (java).
here a snippet of code

```
LambdaFunctionCreater implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {
...
}
```

I have the following method inside my class

```
createNewLambdaFunction (Map<String, String> lambdaEnvProperties) {
try {
    AWSLambdaClientBuilder awsLambdaClient = AWSLambdaClient.builder();
            awsLambdaClient.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("us-east-1").getName());
    CreateFunctionRequest req = new CreateFunctionRequest ();

            req.withDescription("Hello World")
            .withEnvironment(new Environment ().withVariables(myProperties))
            .withFunctionName("Sample Lambda Dynamically created"))
            .withHandler("com.sample.SampleLambda::handleRequest")
            .withRole("MyRole")
            .withRuntime("java8")
            .withMemorySize(128)
            .withTimeout(600)
            .addTagsEntry("Tag1", "Value1")
            .withCode(new FunctionCode().withS3Bucket("mybucket").withS3Key("myfile.jar").withS3ObjectVersion("latestversionid"));

    CreateFunctionResult result = awsLambdaClient.build().createFunction(req);
} catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to create ", e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
}
```

The above call fails with message

> java.lang.NullPointerExceptionnull    at
>   com.capitalone.aws.lambda.handler.LambdaFunctionCreater.createNewLambdaFunction(LambdaFunctionCreater.java:154)null   at
>   com.capitalone.aws.lambda.handler.LambdaFunctionCreater.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionCreater.java:104)null at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)null   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)null at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)null at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)null at
>   lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:456)null at
>   lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:375)null   at
>   lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:1139)null    at
>   lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:278)null at
>   lambdainternal.AWSLambda.(AWSLambda.java:62)null  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)null   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)null   at
>   lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)null

Any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not posting the full code, it's hard to evaluate where the null pointer exception happens.

I'd split the code into more sections and avoid directly passing new objects into single statement like `.withEnvironment(new Environment ().withVariables(myProperties))`. This is very hard to debug since you can't inspect variable value if such statement fails.

I'd also recommend setting up your development environment in such a way that you can run and debug your code directly in your IDE. Debugger watch would immediately tell you which variable is the source of your NullPointerException.

This NullPointerException can be a configuration, permissions or dependency problem.

See also these [Java Lambda examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.FunctionCode).